# How to use typedef recursively?

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef

I want to write a program about courses a person can take each semester.I want to define a data type called CourseTable which is a vector of a struct called Course but in this struct I also have a "prerequisites" variable whose type I've decided to be CourseTable.

```
typedef vector<Course> CourseTable ;
struct Course
{
  ....
  CourseTable prerequisites;
};
```

I get compilation error in either order I put these two declarations.Do you have any suggestions what I should do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to forward declare `Course` before `typedef vector<Course> CourseTable;`.  That would look like

```
struct Course;
typedef vector<Course> CourseTable;
struct Course
{
    CourseTable prerequisites;
};
```

Comment: This is only guaranteed to work since C++17. Before C++17 `std::vector` required its value type to be complete.  (The question is tagged C++11.)

Comment: @walnut That's not a problem here.  `typedef vector<Course> CourseTable;` doesn't actually make an object of `vector` so there is no instantiation.  It is immediately followed by the definition so there shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @NathanOliver i agree with you

Comment: @NutCracker / NathanOliver `CourseTable prerequisites;` causes instantiation and the point of instantiation is immediately preceding the namespace declaration from which it is referenced, i.e. before `Course`'s definition, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Try placing an alias inside the structure:

```cpp
struct Course {
    typedef std::vector<Course> CourseTable;
    CourseTable prerequisites;
};
```

However, more C++-ish solution would be to use [`using`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) keyword for type aliases:

```cpp
struct Course {
    using CourseTable = std::vector<Course>;
    CourseTable prerequisites;
};
```

or forward declare `struct Course` like:

```cpp
struct Course;
using CourseTable = std::vector<Course>;

struct Course {
    CourseTable prerequisites;
};
```

Comment: Be aware that this is only guaranteed to work since C++17. Before that the value type of `std::vector` was required to be complete at that point.